# Nonzero acceleration is compatible with $d|\vec{v}|/dt=0$; why is the reverse not true?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

It is possible to have change in magnitude of velocity w.r.t  time to be zero and magnitude of acceleration to be non zero,

$$\frac{d|\vec{v}|}{dt}=0 \quad \left| \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt} \right| \neq 0\, ,$$

but It is not possible to have change in magnitude of velocity w.r.t time to be non zero and the other to be zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of it like this: if *anything* about the velocity is changing in time then the acceleration is non-zero.
That thing can be magnitude or direction or both.
Therefore, if the change of $|\vec{v}|$ with respect to time is not zero, then the acceleration is, by definition, not zero.

However, we can have a case where the direction of the velocity is changing but the magnitude is not.
In that case we have nonzero acceleration by definition, but $d|\vec{v}|/dt$ is zero.

Comment: Can" Uniform Circular Motion "be an example where direction of velocity is changing but magnitude is constant.

Comment: @MohitSinghChouhan yes, exactly.